# When implementing an interface in Delphi, does it matter if the implementation methods are not in the public section?

Tags: delphi, interface

Given the interface below:

```
ITest = interface ['guidhere']
  procedure TestMethod;
end;
```

Is there any reason to have `TestMethod()` declared as `public` in the implementation class? I have put it in both the `private` and `protected` sections and it does not seem to make a difference. I am just wondering if there are any guidelines, from a design perspective (or any perspective really), that make the `public` section the *correct* section to implement the method in.

Comment: The answer depends on how you are going to call `TestMethod`; if you are going to call it via interface reference only, then it should be made `protected` or `private`; if you also allow to call `TestMethod` via object reference, it should be made `public`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> does it matter if the implementing methods are not in the public section?

As far as the compiler is concerned. It makes no difference.

That being said. Private methods will still be private, even if you can access them through the interface.

```
unit unit1;
....
IItest = interface
  ['{A3D5FEB6-8E29-4EA8-8DC9-7988294EFA65}']
  procedure Test;
end;

TTest = class(TInterfacedObject, IItest)
private
  procedure Test;
end;

unit unit2;
....
var
  TestT: TTest;
  TestI: ITest;
begin
  TestT:= TTest.Create;
  TestI:= TTest.Create;
  TestT.Test;  //will not compile.
  TestI.Test;  //works.
```

The reason for this is that the interface simply has a list of pointers to methods in its VMT. The definition of the method is given in the interface definition.
The compiler only checks if the signatures match.
It does not check the visibility of the method.

As per Allen's comment this is a deliberate design:

> Making the methods private or protected will ensure that you can only access them through the interface. This is a way to enforce a usage contract for the intended use of the object.

Note that this is not an error, or even a bad thing.
Properties can give 'access' to private methods as well:

```
property Items[index: integer] read GetItem write SetItem;
```

Here GetItem and SetItem are often private.
This forces you to access the Items using the property.
When using properties the implementing methods are protected (or worse :-) as a rule. The same logic applies to both properties and interfaces.

More so for interfaces, because if you mix interface access and regular access you'll run into reference counting issues.

**Clean code**
Note that you can have as many visibility sections in a class header as you like.
This way you can put all the interfaced methods in one part and all the non-interfaced methods in another.

```
TTest = class(TInterfacedObject, I1, I2)
//I1 methods
private
  ... private I1 methods here...
protected
  .. more I1 methods
//I2 methods
private
  .. some I2 methods
protected
  ..more I2 methods     
//TTest methods
private
  //data members
public
  constructor Create;
  destructor Destroy; override;
end;
```

That way it's as clear as can be what's what.

Comment: Making the methods private or protected will ensure that you can only access them through the interface. This is a way to enforce a usage contract for the intended use of the object.

Comment: Personally the overuse of `private` is one of the things that bugs me.

Comment: Why? That is what encapsulation is all about. You should never access the private sections of a class. If the author intended something to be accessible, it would have been protected (for descendants to use) or public, for clients to use.

Comment: It's the `overuse` that bugs me. `private` seems to be the default, rather than a reasoned out thought. It's supposed to be OOP after all. **Overusing** `private` kills the inheritance model. Since 2006 !! we've had a fix until a decade later someone decides that that's a bug.  Had they fixed it one, two or even three releases later it would have been better. As it stands it is a violation of trust. I understand that component designers feel exactly the opposite....

Comment: Using private is a way to ensure the proper inheritance contracts are followed and clearly understood. What you call 'overuse', I call a healthy reluctance to being locked into specific implementations. For you to expect that a class author should have "anticipated your specific need" is hubris at the highest scale. A class author can only make generalizations about the potential intended use of the class and allow only specific kinds of extensions.

Comment: The problem is that without helpers, we are reduced to hacking the parent's source code, causing potential breakage in code that uses that original class. Being forcibly locked into the limited vision of the original author just sucks. I understand the need for private, the very limited use of helpers that fixed very limited cases was a good thing.   The hacks using assembly helpers, RTTI and worse that we're reduced to are not.

Comment: Oh, I see. You're upset that the compiler fixed the fact that helpers had allowed access to private members. Well, that was a bug and should have never happened. I've even verified with the original inventor of that feature that it was never intended to be used that way. It was a hole in encapsulation. If you don't want to be "forcibly locked in" then write your own class. That you decided to use another authors class, means you get it, warts and all.

Comment: Let's just say I was blind-sided by that turn of events :-).

Comment: I do hope you agree that allowing such a level of "sanctioned" access to private members through helpers was clearly a bug? That you depended upon it is certainly unfortunate. Aside from affecting all helpers, how is that any worse than the class author changing the internal private implementation while you were using the helper-access trick?

Comment: I'm torn, ask me again in 6 months. The fact that it had been possible to do this for such a long time (nearly 10 years) let me to assume it was somehow OK, OOP be damned.

Comment: The length of time a bug is present has no bearing on whether or not it is a bug. A bug is a bug is a bug. Regardless of when it is discovered and fixed. So by that logic, no longstanding bugs should ever be fixed. Had a conscience decision been made to leave it in, it would have meant tacit endorsement of it and could have lead to a some lock-in for further evolution of the frameworks. As a consumer of the frameworks, it is sometimes hard to envision things as a producer of said frameworks.

Comment: Nice answer Johan, very informative, along with a very informative discussion between you and Allen.  Thank you.

Answer (score -2):

I appreciate this is an old question, but the answer is no longer accurate.

I am using Rio, and [from the documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Object_Interfaces_(Delphi)):

> All members of an interface are public. Visibility specifiers and storage specifiers are not allowed. (But an array property can be declared as default.)

which is indeed what I observe.  An interface defitnion will not allow protected, private or public to be specified.

---

Edit: To incorporate comments to this answer

At the time of writing the compiler does not enforce any level of visibility on the methods which implement the interface.  The methods will be callable through either the interface (interface reference) or through the class (object instance).

As the interface definition insists that all methods are public, when called through an interface reference the implementing methods are public regardless of how they are defined in the implementing class.  As a reference to the interface can be obtained from the object then they are callable from the object, although the caller may have to obtain the interface reference first.

Given that the implementing methods are callable as public through the interface you should consider how helpful it is to not make them public in your class. Restricting the visibility of the methods in the class when they are public in the interface seems to me to be making the code less clear, but other opinions are available!

One of the comments mentioned delegation of the interface. This seems to me to be a distraction as it simply means that when the object retruns the interface reference it returns the reference from the delgated object (which could itself delegate the interface) and ultimately it is the methods of that object whaich are called.

So any class which implements an interface makes the methods which implement the interface available as public when called through the interface.

Comment: Nothing has changed in the case. The OP and [answer of Johan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37031748/1951524) are talking about the visibility in the **implementation class** not about the visibility of interface members. The latter have always had to be public.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Martin, but as the implementing class implements the interface (where all methods must be public) it doesn't really make sense to not make them public.  When calling via the interface the methods from the interface are all public and all available.  When calling via the object this may not be the case, but it seems to me to be unhelpful not to make the visibility the same.  Personally I would like to be able to use an interface to expose public properties with protected accessors, but an Interface doesn't allow that.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to me either. But it is possible. That's why the OP asked the question about any guidelines that are telling us that we have to **implement** in the public section. So he refers to the implementing class not to the interface itself, which in turn your quoted documentation link does.

Comment: Actually, it does make sense to move methods that implement an interface to protected or even private: If you don't want to accidentally call them for an object instance. I do that all the time. Also, since an interface can be implemented by delegation a caller can not even expect the methods to be part of the implementing class.

Comment: Hi @dummzeuch, for class methods any that are part of an interface will be callable with an interface pointer - so you could reduce the visibility but that is completely bypassed by the interface.  And you may implement an interface by delgation to an object, but the interface methods are still public to somebody with the interface reference regardless of where they are implemented.  As per the comment above the OP is about the implementation class which in the case of delegation is the class ultimately delegated to.